# ($396396396\dots$ up to $300$ digits) $\bmod{101}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, divisibility

> Evaluate ($396396396\dots$ up to $300$ digits) $\bmod{101}$

I know that a number when repeated $(p-1)$ times is completely divisible by $p$ where $p$ is a prime number.

But I am not able to understand how to apply that here because here we have repetition in groups of $3.$

Edit :-

I did not understand this base conversion thing, does this property ("a number with (p-1) digits repeated, when divided by p gives a remainder of 0, where p is a prime number ") hold true in all bases ? How can we divide numbers with different bases ? Why are we not converting 101 as well to higher base ?

Comment: Which is  for instance the rest when dividing $396396396396$ by 101?

Comment: Can you find a divisibility test for $101$ similar to the one for $11$?

Comment: You may also observe that $10^3+10^6+10^9+10^{12} \equiv 0 \pmod{101}$ and use that as follows: $$396396396396\ldots396=396[(10^3+10^6+10^9+10^{12})+10^{12}(10^3+10^6+10^9+10^{12})+\dotsb]$$

Comment: How can I apply the property stated in the description to this question?

Comment: You have a number that is repeated $100$ times.  That number is $396$

Comment: @RossMillikan but the number is of 3 digits , how can I consider to be of 1 digit without converting it into a higher base than 396, but then in that case how can I apply the property over here, we need to have same bases for divisor and dividend, right ?

Comment: Your number is $396(1+10^3+10^6+\ldots 10^{297})$, which is the form you are looking for with a base of $1000$

Comment: i.e. the number has polynomial form $\,n = P(b)= a(1+b+b^2+\cdots + b^{99}) = a(b^{100}-1)/(b-1),\,$ for base $\,b=1000,\,$ and repeated "digit"  $\,a = 396\,$ (to connect with my comments on Zag's answer). Note that the digits $d$ in radix $1000$ are the integers $\,0\le d < 1000$ (and here we write them in decimal = radix $10)\ \ $

Answer (score 2):

An answer **if you are really stuck** but you should try to find it on your own using comments bellow your initial post. We can write
$$\begin{align} n & = \overbrace{396 \cdots 396}^{100 \ \text{times}}\\
& = \sum_{k=0}^{99} 396\cdot 10^{3k}\\ 
&= 396\cdot \frac{1000^{100} - 1}{1000 - 1}\\[.3em]
\Rightarrow\ \ 999 n &= 396(1000^{100}-1)\end{align}\qquad\qquad$$

$101$ is prime and does not divide $1000$ so by Fermat's little theorem  $101$ divides $1000^{100} -1,$ so $101$ divides $999n,\,$ but $101$ does not divide $999$, so $101$ divides $n$, by Euclid's Lemma.

Comment: Thank you! But iam looking for a solution where I could use the property stated in the description of question

Comment: @Fin27 this property comes from Fermat's little theorem, so this proof is sort of using it. The proof is the similar, no matter the number of digits of the number that is beeing repeted.

Comment: @BillDubuque My doubt :- I did not understand this base conversion thing, does this property ("a number with (p-1) digits repeated, when divided by p gives a remainder of 0, where p is a prime number ") hold true in all bases ? How can we divide numbers with different bases ? Why are we not converting 101 as well to higher base ?

Comment: @Fin27 The "base" (radix) language is just a way of specifying that $\,n\,$ is a particular (polynomial) function $P(b)$ of the base $\,b,\,$ i.e.  $\, n = P(b) = a(1+b+b^2+\cdots + b^{p-2}) = a(b^{p-1}-1)/(b-1).\,$ The above proof shows that $\,p\nmid b,b\!-\!1\Rightarrow p\mid P(b)\,$ for  *all* integers $\,a,b\,$ and prime $\,p.\,$ Thus we are not restricted to only those values of $\,a\,$ and $\,b\,$ that arise in radix representation, i.e  $\,b\ge 2,\ 0\le a < b.\,$ Rather the proof is really about polynomials of form $P(b)$ closely related to Fermat's little theorem.

Comment: @Fin27 In particular given $P(b)$ there is no need to even mention "base" or radix rep. It is merely a convenient way to state the form of the polynomial expression $P(b).\,$ Also the value of the repeated digit string $\,a\,$ plays no role in the proof - it suffices to shows that the divisibility holds for the case $\,a=1,\,$ i.e. the integer with $\,p-1\,$ repeated ones in base $\,b\,$ (an integer of repeated $\,a\,$ digits equals  $\,a\,$ times an integer of repeated one digits, so remains divisible by $\,p).\ \ $